# How to solve Execution Error in hive?

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, data-warehouse, hiveql

```
hive> CREATE TABLE page_view(viewTime INT, userid BIGINT,
>                 page_url STRING, referrer_url STRING,
>                 ip STRING COMMENT 'IP Address of the User')
> COMMENT 'This is the page view table'
> PARTITIONED BY(dt STRING, country STRING)
> STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE;
```

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for my question, I follow the below method

Set hive.metastore.schema.verification property in hive-site.xml to true, by default it is false.

For further details check this [Hive Schema Tool](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Schema+Tool)